ML find corners of quadrilateral
I am having an assignment to find 4 points of the corners of a quadrilateral shape using ML model. Sometimes one of the angles of the quad is missing (like a folded angle of a page).
Firstly I've tried with image segmentation using MobileNetV3Small as a backbone because the model should be small and fast. It worked good but finding the corners was still an issue. The I've tried finding keypoints of an image following examples like the official keras keypoint detection, medium tutorials, and many other sources but nothing seems to work for me. I've tried modifying them many times. The loss function goes down both for the test and validation but the output is not even close to the desired positions. Tried someting like the following as well:
def conv(model, size, conv2d_kernel, dilation_rate=(1, 1), pooling_size=(2, 2)):
    model.add(Conv2D(size, conv2d_kernel, dilation_rate=dilation_rate))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=max_pooling))
    model.add(Dropout(0.1))

def dense(model, units):
    model.add(Dense(units))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.1))

model = Sequential()
model.add(InputLayer(shape=(224, 224, 3)))

conv(model, size=32, conv2d_kernel=(2, 2))
conv(model, size=64, conv2d_kernel=(3, 3))
conv(model, size=128, conv2d_kernel=(3, 3))

model.add(Flatten())
dense(model, 20)
dense(model, 20)

model.add(Dense(8))
model.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(),
              loss=losses.MeanSquaredLogarithmicError(),
              metrics=[metrics.MeanAbsoluteError()])

Also tried with output shapes like (8) and (4,2) and nothing seems to work. Any help will be appreciated.
PS: Also forgot to add that the dataset is annotated correctly or at least that's what I am seeing on the plot. Also tried with normalizing the coordinates to be between 0 and 1. My input is (224,224,3).

It's not a programming question per say, but more a ML question, so I'd rather ask on CrossValidated or on the ML Stackexchange.  At the first glance, I'd say your model is too shallow, but it's really hard to know what might be the problem without having your dataset, your preprocessing pipeline, etc.

There's also a typo in your conv function,  pooling_size is not used and max_pooling is not defined

Ok, thanks a lot, @Lescurel
